# bootstrap: split, divide, float sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like my sidebar to be split into two columns when rezising to small screen..

My content layout looks like this:
at the left side have a content wrapped in a div like this: 
and at the right hand side I have a few images wrapped in a div like this:

The site from a small screen shows the images placed at the bottom of the content in one column. I would love to know how can I make the images to be split into two columns or more instead of just one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the responsive `col-*` classes:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    content 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
        sidebar 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
        sidebar 2
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to change the padding of the outer sidebar div:

```
.sidebar {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jujbsL4v/1/) (move the divider in the middle to test it)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think my question wasn't clear.   My content layout looks like this: at the left side have a content wrapped in a div like this: and at the right hand side I have a few images wrapped in a div like this:

The site from a small screen shows the images placed at the bottom of the content in one column. I would love to know how can I make the images to be split into two columns or more instead of just one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe you should add a screenshot or a sketch to your question.